# How to get total shipping cost for an order ebay getOrders API

Tags: c#, ebay-api

I'm trying to get the total shipping cost for an order via the eBay GetOrders call in the API. I have created a test order that has 1 item with free postage, one item with a calculated shipping cost, and one item with a flat shipping cost (to cover all scenario's).

I've tried getting the shipping cost for each item using TransactionArray/Transaction/ActualShippingCost and then adding the total. Ive also tried ShippingDetails/ShippingServiceOptions/ShippingServiceCost but I can't seem to figure it out.

Here is the latest code I could come up with but it keeps reporting the error: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

```
double ShippingCost = 0.00;
foreach (TransactionType transaction in orderTrans)
{

    ShippingCost += transaction.ActualShippingCost.Value; //this line causes error
}
MessageBox.Show("Total Shipping Cost is: " + ShippingCost.ToString());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try reading shipping cost from order:

```
if (order.ShippingServiceSelected.ShippingServiceCost != null)
{
    ShippingCost = order.ShippingServiceSelected.ShippingServiceCost.Value
}
```

we use this method in our code and it works.

Comment: Hi, I tried your code and it is returning a value of 0 for the shipping cost. I will update my initial post with the code I am now using as suggested by you.

Comment: Have you set shipping properly for your items? You can also try this `order.ShippingServiceSelected.ShippingServiceAdditionalCost` and see what is returned.

Comment: Hi again, thanks for your response. I have come a step closer to solving this with your help. There is still a problem though. I logged in as the seller and marked the payments as received for the order. This seemed to of made a difference. I have 3 line items in the order. 1 is free postage, the next is $15 and the one after that is $17.40 (calculated shipping). The problem is now it is only getting the shipping for the $15 shipping cost line item ie the total cost of shipping is not being totaled. The shipping should be $32.40. Does the code you gave me only deal with flat rate shipping?

Comment: I got your code to work. The problem was that I needed to mark the items as payment received. I also realised the order that I thought was comprised of three line items, was actually three separate orders thus the reason I was only getting the shipping cost of one item. When I added your code and then processed all three orders, the code you gave me did indeed get the shipping cost for each item/order.

Comment: Sorry I was incorrect. Your code works fine without even marking payment as sent. This has become complicated but to conclude, your code simply works fine. Thanks